# What Types Of Infinitives Are These?

Tags: meaning, grammar, infinitives

1. Do you want to live to be a hundred?
2. I know him to be an honest man.
3. I assumed him to be a thief.

What types of infinitive are these? As we know that these are not the infinitive of purpose. Are these the infinitive of result? Could you help me understand the matter well?

Comment: The first example has two infinitives.  I assume you are concentrating on *to be*

Comment: yes. you guessed right.

Comment: @Henry Incorrect.